# I am converting Crystal reports to SSRS reports. Need to convert an IIF expression with multiple arguments

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, migration, ssrs-2008, reporting

I need to convert an expression with multiple arguments. Below is the crystal expression

```
if Sum ({t_bol_cartons.no_of_cartons}, {t_bol_cartons.hu_id}) = 0 and {t_bol_cartons.sub_status} <> 'S' and {t_bol_cartons.loaded} <> 0 then 1 
else if Sum ({t_bol_cartons.no_of_cartons}, {t_bol_cartons.hu_id}) = 0 and {t_bol_cartons.loaded} = 0  then 0
ELSE Sum ({t_bol_cartons.no_of_cartons}, {t_bol_cartons.hu_id})
```

I have converted in SSRS as below

```
IIf((Fields!no_of_cartons + Value,Fields!hu_id.Value = 0) AND
(Fields!sub_status.Value <> "S") AND (Fields!loaded.Value <> 0),"1",
IIf((Fields!no_of_cartons.Value + Fields!hu_id.Value = 0) AND (Fields!loaded.Value = 0),"0",
(Fields!no_of_cartons.Value + Fields!hu_id.Value)))
```

I am getting an error as

> "The Value expression for the textrun
> 'Sum_cont.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30516]
> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this
> number of arguments."

Please could anyone help with this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you broke it down, and tried one iif statement, test it then add another?  So you can pin down exactly what it doesnt like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is first part is wrong, you have `Fields!no_of_cartons + Value` instead of `Fields!no_of_cartons.Value`

Try

```
IIf(
  (Fields!no_of_cartons.Value + Fields!hu_id.Value = 0) AND (Fields!sub_status.Value <> "S") AND (Fields!loaded.Value <> 0),
  "1", 
  IIf(
      (Fields!no_of_cartons.Value + Fields!hu_id.Value = 0) AND (Fields!loaded.Value = 0),
      "0",
      (Fields!no_of_cartons.Value + Fields!hu_id.Value)
      )
    )
```